# how to find channelId in android from youtube data api

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, subscribe

I want to implement YouTube subscribe button in Android. When user click on subscribe button it should not redirect to YouTube app.
Can anyone help me with this.

```
String channelId = getChannelId();
```

It is saying cannot resolve `getChannelId()`. Can anyone suggest what is missing in code?

Comment: Try to make a call to [Channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), a successful call returns a [response which contains the channel id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource).

Comment: @noogui Thanks for the link you provided. Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "localizations");
Its saying cannot resolve Auth.authorize() can u help me with this do i need to import any library